# Kernel methods - How do the infinite dimensions arise?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, eigenvalues

I'm going through the Kernel chapter from [Kevin Murphy's Machine Learning book](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/) and he talks about the importance of positive definite or Mercer kernels:

[image]

My question comes from the last sentence: What makes φ depend on the eigen *functions* of κ, and how does that make $D$ be a potentially infinite dimensional space?

I think I'm missing something critical for the understanding of kernels and SVMs.

Comment: Note that the $\phi$ of (14.13) is _not_ the $\phi$ of (14.12) and slightly before. That first $\phi$, which maps $\mathcal X$ to $\mathbb R^n$ if there are $n$ entries, is dataset-dependent; the second, which maps $\mathcal X$ to some Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, is independent of the data and defined only by the kernel. (Murphy calls this $\mathbb R^D$ and then notes that somehow $D$ is supposed to be a possibly infinite dimensional space – he's being quite sloppy here and I don't like this description at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive definite symmetric matrix $A$ can be written as:

$$A=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k e_ke^T_k,$$

where $Ae_k=\lambda_ke_k$ and $e_k$ are the normalized eigenvectors of $A$. This is completely equivalent to the eigendecomposition form: $A=U\Sigma U^T$, where $U$ is the unitary matrix whose columns are $e_j$. In particular, $A$ can also be thought of as a function function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$:

$$[A]_{ij}:=A(i,j)=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_ke_{ki}e_{kj}=\phi^T(i)\phi(j),$$

where $e_{kj}:=[e_k]_j$, i.e. the j'th component of eigenvector $e_k$, and $\phi^T(i):=(\sqrt{\lambda_1}e_{1i},\sqrt{\lambda_2}e_{2i},\cdots,\sqrt{\lambda_n}e_{ni})$. Finally, when we act $A$ on a vector $x$, we write

$$[Ax]_{i}=(Ax)(i):=\sum_{k=1}^nA(i,k)x_k.$$

A positive definite, symmetric kernel $\kappa(s,s')$ is a function from $\mathcal{X}^2$ to  $\mathbb{R}$. You can think of it as an infinite matrix where indices are continuous instead of just discrete. Thus kernels act on vectors which are now functions. Thus instead of a vector $x=x(i)$ with components $x_i$ ($i=1,2,\cdots,n$), we write $x(s)$, where $s$ is continuous, and therefore $x$ is a function of $s$. There are technical restrictions on what kind of function $x$ can be, which you can learn about if you lookup $L^2$ spaces, specifically: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(s)|^2ds<\infty$.

A natural definition for defining the action of $\kappa$ on $x$ is through an integral over the continuum of indices, as opposed to the usual discrete sum for matrices:

$$\kappa x=(\kappa x)(s):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \kappa(s,s')x(s')ds'.$$
Also just like in the discrete case, $\kappa$ has eigen**functions** $e_j=e_j(s)$:

$$(\kappa e_j)(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \kappa(s,s')e(s')ds'=\lambda_j e_j(s).$$

The fact that there are infinitely many eigenfunctions for $\kappa$ comes from the fact that the space of functions on which $\kappa$ acts on is infinite dimensional. Again, a very low brown way of seeing this is to realize that $x=x(s)$ can be thought of as a vector with a continuum of indices. Through the abstract nonsense of Hilbert Schmidt operator theory, one can show (somewhat nontrivially) that if $\kappa$ is analogous to a positive definite matrix, then it possesses a *discrete*, possibly infinite set of eigenvectors and non-negative eigenvalues, which allows us to write the analog:

$$\kappa(s,s')=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_j e_j(s)e_j(s')=\phi(s)^T\phi(s'),$$

where $\phi^T(s):=(\sqrt{\lambda_1}e_1(s),\sqrt{\lambda_2}e_2(s),\cdots)$. Notice the dots signify this could potentially be an infinitely long vector.

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this. $s$ in this case is any real-valued vector, and since there are infinitely many possible vectors, we can see the kernel as a mapping from these infinite vectors to $\mathbb{R}$? I can understand what $\mathbb{R}^2$ is but have more trouble with interpreting $X^2$